# How to make Samba share to NOT ASK FOR PASSWORD

Tags: samba, file-sharing

NOTE: I have read probably up to 50 different pages describing how to setup public Samba share in the span of **2 YEARS** and nothing ever worked for me. I don't know how much RTFM I need to set this stuff.

I need/want to setup a completely open public file share on my home server for two workstations.

Setup is as follows:

*Server*:

- Debian Wheezy
- `sudo smbd --version` gives me `Version 3.6.6`.
- 2 local partitions which I want to share, formatted in NTFS due to being old and taken from Windows machine. I cannot format them to ext* FS because they have a lot of data I cannot (yet) move anywhere else.
- machine named "homeserv" for lack of originality.

*Client*:

1. Debian Testing (Jessie)
2. Windows 7 (2 different machines). In fact, my machine is Debian/Windows dualboot, and my wife's machine is Windows only.

My smb.conf after distillation looks as follows (*verbatim*, nothing else is there):

```
[global]
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad User

[disk1]
  comment = Disk 1 on 400GB HDD
  path = /media/disk1
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0755

[disk2]
  comment = Disk 2 on 400GB HDD
  path = /media/disk2
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0755
```

On both client machines, in both Debian and Windows I get the same result: login/password dialog. NO COMBINATION of `security = user`, `map to guest = Bad user`, `security = share`, `guest ok = yes` and such helped.

Windows 7 shows login/password dialog right after I click on the shared machine in network neighborhood. `smb://homeserv/` file path in Debian (in any file browser) shows me two folders: `disk1` and `disk2`, as intended, by trying to open them bring the login/password dialog.

So, what I lack in the scheme to NOT HAVE to enter login/password? This is usability question, I will not create a user-based authentication for file junkyard.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, I have found an answer myself.

As this is *absolutely not obvious* from the docs and HOWTOs and whatever, the reason this thing asks for password is because it cannot map guest user to the **owner of the directory being shared**.

I have NTFS partitions which I need to mount RW so I used the following setup in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1  /media/disk1  ntfs defaults,noexec,noatime,relatime,utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0       2
/dev/sdb2  /media/disk2  ntfs defaults,noexec,noatime,relatime,utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0       2
```

The most important pieces of config are `uid` and `gid` (maybe only `uid`, don't know).
They are set to the UID and GID of the user `jonnie` set up on the server (obviously not root). So, when ntfs-3g will mount these disks, everything will be owned by him.

After that, I have added this user to the Samba registry (or maybe created new identical one, don't care):

```
# smbpasswd -a jonnie
```

It asked for password, I have entered the same as for the main system.

After that, I have added the `force user` and `force group` settings to the `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  netbios name = HOMESERV
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad User

[disk1]
  comment = Disk 1 on 400GB HDD
  path = /media/disk1
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 666
  directory mask = 777
  force user = jonnie
  force group = jonnie

[disk2]
  comment = Disk 2 on 400GB HDD
  path = /media/disk2
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 666
  directory mask = 777
  force user = jonnie
  force group = jonnie
```

So, *most important* piece of config relevant to me was `force user`.

Courtesy of the [Samba HOWTO](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html#id2554637)

Comment: "obviously not root". That's actually not so obvious. Samba has dozens of failure modes. Most result in an identical error messages. That's why you spent so much time in fruitless Google searches. Not only will a single search bring up a mixture of problems, but the answers found will also suffer from the same confusion. Using root eliminates the Linux side of security, but also allows you to diagnose the problem. If it works as root, you have a security issue at Linux level, If Samba still fails, the issue is within Samba's idea of users (they're different, and should have had unique errors)

Comment: As of 2020, this approach did not seem to work for me, but logging once as "guest" user with a made up password and telling the file manager to save it helped me solve this issue, as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116497/how-to-dont-show-samba-authentication-window-for-anonymous-user/1116658

Comment: "So, most important piece of config relevant to me was force user." That did it! Thank you! +1

Comment: Thank you, it worked. BTW, I gave empty password to `sudo smbpasswd -a [user]`, it worked too.

Answer (score 6):

The config can be shorter:

Create unix user jonnie

```
sudo useradd jonnie -s /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Create smbuser

```
sudo smbpasswd -a jonnie
```

Create the Linux directory to share

```
mkdir /mysmbshare
```

Change the owner of the directory to jonnie

```
sudo chown jonnie /mysmbshare
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
  workgroup = MyWorkGroup
  server string = Hello, use me
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad User
  guest account = jonnie
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  
[the_public_share]
   path = /mysmbshare
   writable = yes
   printable = no
   public = yes
```

All files are owned by jonnie and everyone has rw access to the files.

Comment: Yep, "change the owner of the directory to jonnie" is probably the most important part here. Thank you for much shorter solution!

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way to have an open Samba share is to have:

```
# ----------------------- Standalone Server Options ------------------------
#
# Scurity can be set to user, share(deprecated) or server(deprecated)
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.

        security = share
        passdb backend = tdbsam
```

and have shares defines as such:

```
[export]
   comment = Data Export Directory
   path = /data/export
   read only = no
   public = yes
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 666
   directory mask = 777
```

Restart the daemon.

For Windows 7 clients, as of 2014, I've needed to set the domain policy: *digitally sign communications from always* to DISABLE.

Comment: My God, changing domain policy for supposedly public shares... (facepalm).

Okay, thank you anyway, but no, I tried this just now and accessing `smb://homeserv/disk1` still requires a password in Debian. I used Dolphin and Krusader file browsers. Maybe it's something in KDE though.

Comment: hey that worked! :D `public = yes` and `777` permissions did the trick (Win 10 hosting Ubuntu 18.04). Fortunately it is on my personal workstation so I don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by "hijarian" at the time of writing is not ideal for the main reason that if the share is writable, then you cannot know which user wrote to the share. If it is a guest mount, then who cares about security and you can stop reading this now. If you care about security, read on...

By default, Windows passes the username and password of the currently logged-in user. This means that the password set with `smbpasswd` should match that of the user's password on the Windows client. The password may not be the empty string (at least I have not found a way to force this while also passing the authentication step).

File shares are often group-oriented (group of users need access to the same data). This is why I prefer to implement shares by groups (not by users like in most documentation):

```
[Musik]
writeable = true 
path = "/mnt/remote/smb/5TB/Media/Music"
valid users = @smbmedia
create mode = 2774 
directory mode = 2775
```

Note the `@smbmedia`. This means that anyone in the group `smbmedia` may access this share. I have `create mode` and `directory mode` in there, but its mostly for good measure and redundant.

Because this share is writable, the default umask will apply. I like to  override this because I want ensure that new files are owned by the group `smbmedia` and the user should be set to the user who created the file (for record keeping).

Set the sticky bit to ensure new directories keep the same ACLs (which we'll set next. **CAVEAT**: Without `create mode` and `directory mode`, and  relying on only ACLs, note that ACLs cannot set the group sticky bit. The group stick bit will therefore only work for new directories at 1 level  below the base level of the share. This means that
newly created directories at level 1 will have the ACLs applied minus the group sticky bit, so that level 2 directories will assume the primary group permissions of the user that created the new directory, and not necessarily the "shared" group permissions (something like this). There are two ways to deal with this: One way it to use something like `inotify` to watch for new directories and apply the group sticky bit on newly created directories recursively. The other way is to push the responsibility to your samba daemon by using something like `directory mode = 2775` to force the group sticky bit on all newly created directories.

```
SHARE_PATH="/mnt/remote/smb/5TB/Media"
chmod g+s "${SHARE_PATH}"
```

Set the default ACLs for new files to ensure the group remains constant

```
setfacl -d -m 'g:smbmedia:rwx' "${SHARE_PATH}"
```

Now you can be sure that new files will be created with the correct permissions so that they can be seen and changed by smb client users. This will allow anyone in the `smbmedia` group to change files owned by other people, however. You can adjust the ACLs accordingly.

List of other things to do:

- disable netbios (old crap)
- disable wins (old crap)
- start wsdd server https://github.com/christgau/wsdd

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.  I'm sure you can take most of it out.  It took me a lot of messing around to get it to work.  file permissions on the directory need to be liberal as well of course 777 etc. and then trim it back a bit if you want more security.  I'm sure some of these settings could probably be removed and it would still work.  I've used it on Linux Mint 20 and 21, Linux Lite 6 and Kali Linux (All are Ubuntu based).  It always works great for me and when connecting from a Windows 10 machine it doesn't prompt to authenticate.

I also usually install WSDD on my Linux machines so Windows can find them more easily.  https://github.com/christgau/wsdd  You can usually get it via APT.

```
sudo apt install wsdd
```

Cheers!

```
usershare owner only = false
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = file

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

server role = standalone server obey pam restrictions = yes

unix password sync = yes

passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u passwd chat = 
Enter\snew\s\spassword:* %n\n Retype\snew\s\spassword:* %n\n 
password\supdated\ssuccessfully .

pam password change = yes

map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes

[Your Share Name]
    comment = Whatever you want it to say
    path = /PathToSharedDirectory
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
```